# Select all siblongs except currently hovered element using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have couple of spiner-powered inputs on my form, and on some event I want to get all elements with class `ui-icon` except one which currently meets some requrements (not mandatory hovered). I have not issues with selecting, for example, `inputs` because each one has uniq `ID` with something like:

```
var otherSpinnerButtons = $(e.target)
    .parents('.sub')
    .find('input[type="text"]:not(#' + e.target.id + ')')
    .siblings('a.ui-spinner-button');
```

But now I need to do the same with `ui-icon` elements which hasn't `ID`. At any moment I have element which should be excluded from jquery search. How to achieve it?

Html code markup is below.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="block1">
        <span class="ui-element">
            <input type="text" id="SomeUniqId1" />
            <a href="" class="ui-spinner-button">
                <span class="ui-icon">^</span>
            </a>
            <a href="" class="ui-spinner-button">
                <span class="ui-icon">v</span>
            </a>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="block2">
        <!-- The same as in block1 -->
    </div>

    <div class="block3">
        <!-- The same as in block1 -->
    </div>

    ...
</div>
```

Comment: `$(this).closest('.ui-spinner-button').siblings('a.ui-spinner-button')` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
var otherSpinnerButtons = $(e.target)
.parents('.sub')
.find('input[type="text"]').not(this)
.siblings('a.ui-spinner-button');
```